# CartThrob Subscriptions Add-on - Is it a good fit?

Tags: add-on, cartthrob

I am just trying to check that the project I am looking into would be a good fit for CartThrob Pro with Subscriptions, here is a quick run through:

The client will be selling normal (physical) products through the main area of the site for which CartThrob Pro will do nicely, taking payments via SagePay Server.

However, there will also be a club section where customers can purchase packages of products on a recurring basis. For example they might have a package called ‘Starter’ consisting of 3 products (picked by the client not the customer) being sent out every month for £10 p/m. Another might be called ‘Advanced’ where they send out 8 products per month for £20 p/m.

Also the product category (maybe spicy or mild) within a package can be chosen from a list by the customer, so for the ‘Starter’ they can choose up to 3 product categories from a list of maybe 10 different ones.

What can the customer update regarding their subscriptions? For example would they be able to change to a different set of product categories for that subscription to be sent out the next month? Can they easily upgrade to a another subscription plan too?

The client would obviously need to be able to manage the packages of products in the same way as they manage the normal products.

Looking through the docs etc CartThrob Pro plus Subscriptions would fit this nicely.

Can anyone shed some light as to whether this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe I can't think of any reason why Cartthrob and CT Subscriptions wouldn't be a good fit in this scenario. Customers will be able to edit their subscription plans and you'll be able to create dynamic subscriptions if needed.

One thing to note though is that if you're setting up subscriptions then you'll need to go with a token based system. This basically sees you capture a token from the payment gateway which can be sent later on to make the charge even when the custom is not present. For this you'll need to ensure that your payment gateway supports a token system. [SagePay does provide one](http://www.sagepay.com/token-system) but just double check that you're setup to use this system in your plan with them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ian. 
I have already told the client that we'll need to make sure their SagePay account is setup to use Tokens.
Just to make sure, can the customer change the products within a plan they have already subscribed to?
Or would they have to cancel that plan and start a new order?
Thanks, Wes.